# print the minimum for each row in a dataset in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to print the minimum (and maximum) value for each row in a dataset. I can get it to print one row by using
min(dataset1[1,])

but how can I amend this to do it for all 100 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `apply` function to run methods over each row of a data frame. For example, the following will find the minimum value of each row of the data frame `dataset`:

```
apply(dataset, 1, min)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work? Using dplyr package.

```
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(c1 = round(rnorm(10,10,1)),
                   c2 = round(rnorm(10,10,1)),
                   c3 = round(rnorm(10,10,1)))
dat %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(row_min = min(c_across(c1:c3)), row_max = max(c_across(c1:c3)))
```

```
# A tibble: 10 x 5
# Rowwise: 
      c1    c2    c3 row_min row_max
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     9    11     9       9      11
 2    10    10    10      10      10
 3    12    10     9       9      12
 4    10    10     9       9      10
 5    10     9     9       9      10
 6    12    12     8       8      12
 7    10    10    11      10      11
 8     9     8    10       8      10
 9     9    11     9       9      11
10    10    10    11      10      11
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `range` which gives minimum and maximum simultaneously.

```
t(apply(d, 2, range))
#          [,1]      [,2]
# X1 -0.5646982 1.3709584
# X2 -0.1061245 2.0184237
# X3 -1.3888607 2.2866454
# X4 -2.6564554 1.3201133
# X5 -1.7813084 1.8951935
# X6 -1.7631631 0.4600974
```

For sake of speed, try

```
matrixStats::colRanges(as.matrix(d))
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
d <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(5*6), 5, 6))
```